# Pell's d prime (often) implies that x(d-1) is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have found a few patterns in my study of Pell’s equation x(d)^2-dy(d)^2=1.
One is this: If d is a prime then x(d-1) is also prime.

It doesn’t hold for all primes, but it is a pattern which holds for 17 of the 21 first (relevant) primes from 2 to 100. (There are more primes below 100 but several values are irrelevant since x(d-1) does not exist d=2, 5, 17 and 37).

I know that in many cases you will find a pattern which is just from statistics with just a few numbers.  I believe the phenomenon even has its own law, “the law of small numbers”   (among which “anything can happen”).

My inability to use mathematical software makes it impractical to improve my statistics. Does anybody know if this pattern prevails for a collection of the equations with higher numbers of d, or if there might be a reason for such a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it by $x(d)$ you mean the $x$ for the smallest solution in positive integers.

Since $x(d-1)$ satisfies $x^2-(d-1)y^2=1$ it cannot have any common factor with $d-1$ or with $y$. For odd primes $d$ this rules out 2 and at least one other prime $<d$ as possible factors for $x$, which should make the occurence of prime $x(d-1)$ very slightly less surprising.

Checking the occurence for the first $N$ primes I got this table, which illustrates that the cases where $x(d-1)$ are prime are a minority for $N$ larger than 150, and look to be a diminishing proportion as $N$ grows.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
N & \mathrm{Relevant} & x(d-1)~\mathrm{is~prime} & \mathrm{fraction} \\
\hline\\
25 & 21 & 17 & 81\% \\
100 & 92 & 54 & 59\% \\
150 & 69 & 150 & 49\% \\
1000 & 983 & 252 & 26\% \\
10000 & 9949 & 1220 & 12\% \\
20000 & 19932 & 1987 & 10\% \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thank you. I expected the prime number occurrence to somewhat better than ramdom, but now I am not so sure. It may be another case of the law of small numbers.